# How to insert bulgarian characters string into MySQL database using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert a string (which consists of bulgarian characters as follows 'КИ ПЕПСИ') into MySQL database using JDBC driver.

Here follows the snippet of the code how I am trying to insert.

```
 String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://myurl.amazonaws.com/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=Cp1251";

   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "mypassword";

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

   String SQL = "INSERT INTO tmptab(city) VALUES('КИ ПЕПСИ')";

   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

   stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

The DDL for the table tmptab is as follows:

```
create table tmptab (city varchar(255) COLLATE cp1251_bulgarian_ci DEFAULT NULL) DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 COLLATE=cp1251_bulgarian_ci;
```

But when I see values in the database it is as follows:

> City '?? ?????'

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here. I am just assuming that it is related to charset encoding. I would appreciate if any help can be provided.

One more thing I would like to mention that when I insert data into local system, it inserts properly. But when I try to insert into MySQL database running into amazon cloud I do not get proper value inserted. I just see ???????.

Comment: Where do you see those ? In java, in mysql console...?

Comment: When I run  select * from tmptab in mysql workbench, I see ????. If I print in java console, I see same(????) on java console as well.

Comment: If I print SQL statement on java console as follows System.out.println(SQL), I see the following text: INSERT INTO tmptab(city) VALUES('?? ?????')

Comment: Do you really want to use `useUnicode=true` when you are using the cp1251 character set (which is *not* Unicode)? Also, the `&amp;` in your connection URL looks suspicious (i.e., it probably really should be just `&`).

Comment: Thank you Gord Thompson. it is working fine after I changed the url as follows: static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://sdax-retail-dev.cd50doqou1ik.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/sdax_qa?characterEncoding=Cp1251";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Gord Thompson for quick help.

For other users, there was problem with the url. I removed useUnicode and & string from the url as follows:

static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://sdax-retail-dev.cd50doqou1ik.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/sdax_qa?characterEncoding=Cp1251";

It is working as expected now.